# Move window to Master in XMonad without swapping

Tags: xmonad, master

mod-return currently *swaps* the focused window with the master window. What I want is to move the focused window to the master and have the rest move over one place. So the end result is as if I had pressed mod-shift-k a couple of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Xmonad.StackSet.shiftMaster` does exactly that.

Simply add a line looking like this to your keys configuration:

```
, ((modMask,               xK_Return), windows W.shiftMaster)
```

Or, if you use `additionalKeysP` from `XMonad.Util.EZConfig`,

```
, ("M-<Return>", windows W.shiftMaster)
```